# Pandas Group by Week without exceeding a month

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform a group by week in my pandas dataframe, without exceeding a month. E.g.:

```
                Date   Value
0  2021-01-15   4
1  2021-01-17   3
2  2021-01-19  10
3  2021-02-04   1
```

The groupby week should look something like this:

```
                Week   Sum_value
0  2021-01-01-2021-01-06   0
...
3  2021-01-29-2021-01-31   5
```

So a week should not span over 2 months.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I think you may want to generate derived (from date) columns for year, month and week number (i.e. week of year) and then group by all 3 columns. But I'm not 100% sure how you got the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

we need minimal and reproducible example to answer. lets make

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
date = pd.date_range('2024-01-01', '2024-02-02')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date, 
                   'Value': np.random.randint(0, 10, len(date))})
```

df

```
Date    Value
0   2024-01-01  5
1   2024-01-02  0
2   2024-01-03  3
... ... ...
30  2024-01-31  2
31  2024-02-01  3  <--next month
32  2024-02-02  8  <--next month
33 rows × 2 columns
```

**Code**

```
# if your Date column is not datetime type, convert to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# make grouper by week and month
grp1 = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
grp2 = df['Date'].dt.to_period('W')

# get you desired output
out = (df.groupby([grp1, grp2])
       .agg(Week=('Date', 'first'), 
            last=('Date', 'last'), 
            Value_sum=('Value', 'sum'))
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .assign(Week=lambda x: x['Week'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
               + '-' + x.pop('last').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
)
```

out

```
    Week                    Value_sum
0   2024-01-01-2024-01-07   30
1   2024-01-08-2024-01-14   40
2   2024-01-15-2024-01-21   35
3   2024-01-22-2024-01-28   36
4   2024-01-29-2024-01-31   7
5   2024-02-01-2024-02-02   11
```

---

To set the first 7 days of each month as the first week regardless of the day of the week, set grp as follows:

```
grp1 = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
grp2 = df['Date'].dt.day.sub(1).floordiv(7)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there is one small problem. If a new month starts, it should have one week as a period, but here (at the start of February and march), it only has 3-4 days. :                                               
15.01.2024-21.01.2024 00:07:12
22.01.2024-28.01.2024 00:06:36
29.01.2024-31.01.2024 00:02:46
01.02.2024-04.02.2024 00:01:21
05.02.2024-11.02.2024 00:02:44
12.02.2024-18.02.2024 00:03:49
19.02.2024-25.02.2024 01:04:43
26.02.2024-29.02.2024 00:02:08
01.03.2024-03.03.2024 00:01:49
04.03.2024-09.03.2024 00:08:25
13.03.2024-17.03.2024 00:02:52

Comment: @bunus19 chk my update answer

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution could be this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2021-01-15', 
                               '2021-01-17','2021-01-19', '2021-02-04'],'Value': [4,3,10,1]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: f'{r.start_time.date()}-{r.end_time.date()}')

df_grouped = df.groupby('Week').sum()

print(df_grouped)
```

The output is the following:

```
Week                   Value
2021-01-11-2021-01-17      7
2021-01-18-2021-01-24     10
2021-02-01-2021-02-07      1
```